# Laravel Websockets Active list

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

Everyone!
I'm using beyondcodes/laravel-websockets. I have a webhook route:
WebSocketsRouter::webSocket('/my-websocket/{appKey}', \App\WebSocketHandler::class);

This will be called by users from their mobile app. Now I want to send some data to a few selected users. I have the listing of users whom I have to send data, but not the listing of active connections and which user is using which connection.How can I do so?

So far I have created some logic in websockethandler class:

```
class WebSocketHandler implements MessageComponentInterface
{
    /** @var \BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\WebSockets\Channels\ChannelManager */
    protected $channelManager;
    
    public $querystring;

    public function __construct(ChannelManager $channelManager)
    {
        $this->channelManager = $channelManager;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $connection)
    {
    return $this
        ->verifyAppKey($connection)
        ->limitConcurrentConnections($connection)
        ->generateSocketId($connection)
        ->establishConnection($connection);
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $connection, MessageInterface $message)
    {
    $body = collect(json_decode($message->getPayload(),true));
        $payload = $body->get('payload');
        $message->respond();
        StatisticsLogger::webSocketMessage($connection);
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $connection)
    {
        $this->channelManager->removeFromAllChannels($connection);
        DashboardLogger::disconnection($connection);
        StatisticsLogger::disconnection($connection);
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $connection, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof WebSocketException) {
            $connection->send(json_encode(
                $exception->getPayload()
            ));
        }
    }

    protected function verifyAppKey(ConnectionInterface $connection)
    {
        $appKey = QueryParameters::create($connection->httpRequest)->get('appKey');

        if (! $app = App::findByKey($appKey)) {
            throw new UnknownAppKey($appKey);
        }

        $connection->app = $app;

        return $this;
    }

    protected function limitConcurrentConnections(ConnectionInterface $connection)
    {
        if (! is_null($capacity = $connection->app->capacity)) {
            $connectionsCount = $this->channelManager->getConnectionCount($connection->app->id);
            if ($connectionsCount >= $capacity) {
                throw new ConnectionsOverCapacity();
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    protected function generateSocketId(ConnectionInterface $connection)
    {
        $socketId = sprintf('%d.%d', random_int(1, 1000000000), random_int(1, 1000000000));

        $connection->socketId = $socketId;

        return $this;
    }

    protected function establishConnection(ConnectionInterface $connection)
    {
    $orderid = AModel::create($connection->httpRequest)->get('orderid');
    $respones = BModel::select('latitude','longitude')->where('order_id',$orderid)->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->first();
        $connection->send(json_encode($respones));

        DashboardLogger::connection($connection);

        StatisticsLogger::connection($connection);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Laravel Reverb ( https://reverb.laravel.com/ ) launches tomorrow. I would recommend you check that out.

Comment: Please don't use this package, it's abandoned